# Passing a string as a function argument and using it as a dynamic key name in object.assign

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

I have a method in a service (my app is an Angular 5 app that is written in TypeScript) that takes two arguments, one is an event object and the other is a string which is the key of an object I store in the browser's web storage.

The method assigns a new object to the browser's web storage and combining it with a second object, here's my code

```
setPaginationObject(event: any, list: string) {
    let sitePagination = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('sitePagination')) || {};
    sitePagination = Object.assign(sitePagination, {list: event});
    sessionStorage.setItem('sitePagination', JSON.stringify(sitePagination));
}
```

Here's how I would call in in a component:

```
public onPaginateChange(event: any): void {
    this.paginationService.setPaginationObject(event, 'usersList');
}
```

My problem is that I need the argument to be assigned to the dynamic property used in the `Object.assign` code, as currently the declaration uses a the label "list" rather than the string passed as an argument. How can I pass an argument in my method and dynamically use it as a key name / label the Object.assign second argument?

I thought I could do something like this:

```
sitePagination = Object.assign(sitePagination, {`${list}`: event});
```

but that doesn't work, or I could change the argument signature to something like this so the object is formatted in the component and not the service

```
this.paginationService.setPaginationObject({'usersList': event});
```

and in the service

```
setPaginationObject(obj: any) {
    let sitePagination = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('sitePagination')) || {};
    sitePagination = Object.assign(sitePagination, obj);
    sessionStorage.setItem('sitePagination', JSON.stringify(sitePagination));
}
```

The above seems fine but I now just want to know how I could dynamically set the key name in the `Object.assign` code.

Thanks in advance, sorry if my wording is bad, if it is I shall rework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a computed property inside your object literal:

```
let list: string = 'userList'
let obj = {[list]: 'Value'}; // will be { 'userList': 'Value'} at runtime
```